# Trying to write less_than symbol twice("<<") using XSLT. It doesn't work if I try writing it twice

Tags: xml, xslt, symbols

I don't know why, but whatever I try to write this string "<<" using XSLT, the parser gives me an error; I tried the same with writing greater_then symbol twice(">>") and it worked.
These are the ways I tried to use:

```
1 - <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;&lt;</xsl:text>
2 - <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;&#60;</xsl:text>
3 - <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#60;&#lt;</xsl:text>
4 - <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#60;&#60;</xsl:text>
5 - <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#lt;</xsl:text><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#lt;</xsl:text>
```

...none of them work. Does someone of you know why?     Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** 
I tried using many parser through internet, like on the websites: altervista; w3c.
The error I get is: "XML: non well-formed"

Even trying this little xslt code, it gives me the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/logs">
        <html>
            <body>
                &lt;&lt;
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this works...:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/logs">
        <html>
            <body>
                &lt;
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Which parser do you use, which error do you get? Using `&lt;&lt;` should do.

Comment: I edited the main post.

Comment: And I edited it again with a little xslt code as example

Comment: ..? Try `&amp;lt;&amp;lt;` for funsies. What is your target `xsl:output`, by the way?

Comment: I'm new into xslt, Im using it since yesterday, and I never used the <xsl:output> element.
Anyway, I tried with &amp;lt;&amp;lt; and the output result like "&amp;<"

EDIT: I used w3c parser to test what you told me, but, using altervista it gives an error.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: What is the XSLT processor?

Comment: You are using an online tool like http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog - right? There, `&lt;&lt;` leads to an error, while `&lt;` is working. To me, it looks like a limitation of those online tools...

Comment: Yes and, even using altervista it gives me an error.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have written, only the tools you are using are yielding an error. Use a good tool to write XSL -- like download oXygen or another XSL editor.

Comment: I was trying to use altervista and I've the site on it, it should work ://

Comment: I just tried with Saxon 9.1.0.3 and it returns properly escaped characters for `output method="xml"` and `"html"` and the literal characters for `"text"`.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT code is XML and within XML you need to escape any `<` less-than symbol not to be used as markup as `&lt;` and consequently two of them as `&lt;&lt;` as you have done. 
In that case XML parsing and XSLT processing should work fine and does for me at http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2CP which simply has the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logs/>
```

the XSLT code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/logs">
        <html>
            <body>
                &lt;&lt;
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result

```
<html>
   <body>
      &lt;&lt;

   </body>
</html>
```

If your test environment gives you an error on `&lt;&lt;` then it is broken and not a usable environment to learn, test, run or debug XSLT code.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "none of them work" it depends what you mean by "work". Any of the five approaches you have given in the question should correctly produce a `<<` in your output, but an output that contains an unescaped `<<` can never be well-formed XML. If your testing tool tries to parse such an output as if it were XML then that parsing process *must* fail with the error you are seeing.

Your later example of `<body>&lt;&lt;</body>` is a correct way to produce an *escaped* `<<` in your output, and if your testing tool cannot handle that then the bug is in the tool rather than the XSLT code.